# Ubuntu 16.04 How to switch to Wicd Network Manager cleanly?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, networkmanager, wicd

I am having issues with the gnome network manager and I have always liked the wicd network manager.

I have already tried to reconfigure using `dpkg --reconfigure` to no avail.  So I would like to just switch over, but I want to do it cleanly so that bootup doesn't look for .conf settings from network manager.

Also I have already installed wicd so that I can actually use the internet.  I
Any help, especially command line reference would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Archlinux-wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wicd) , To use WICD you need to disable other network daemons (netctl, netcfg, dhcpcd, NetworkManager)

> Warning: Running multiple network managers will cause problems, so it is important to disable all other network management daemons.
>
> First, stop all previously running network daemons (like `netctl`, `netcfg`, `dhcpcd`, `NetworkManager`).
>   Disable any existing network management services, including `netctl`, `netcfg`, `dhcpcd`, and `networkmanager`

You can find a list of the currently running services with `systemctl --type=service` and then stop them.